# is there any diffs hugepaged/nohuge ram map to cpu cache?

Tags: caching, memory, ram, tlb

my server cpu info :
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v3 @ 3.20GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               3200.000
CPU max MHz:           3200.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              6391.94
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K

os kernel version:
3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64

i'm doing some performance test on my server,and got some confusing on hugepaged ram issues.

as i use code from  https://github.com/torvalds/test-tlb,
and run test shell scripts as:

```
for i in 128k 512k 1M 2M 4M 8M 16M 32M 64M 128M; do echo "$i:"; ./test-tlb -H 4G $i ; ./test-tlb 4G $i ; ./test-tlb -Hr 4G $i ; ./test-tlb -r 4G $i ; done
```

i got the following results:

```
128k:
 87.24ns (~279.2 cycles)
 98.24ns (~314.4 cycles)
 90.07ns (~288.2 cycles)
108.19ns (~346.2 cycles)
512k:
 87.17ns (~279.0 cycles)
 92.55ns (~296.1 cycles)
 90.51ns (~289.6 cycles)
 95.03ns (~304.1 cycles)
1M:
 88.28ns (~282.5 cycles)
 34.73ns (~111.1 cycles)
 90.76ns (~290.4 cycles)
 36.47ns (~116.7 cycles)
2M:
 91.01ns (~291.2 cycles)
 34.91ns (~111.7 cycles)
 91.56ns (~293.0 cycles)
 35.51ns (~113.6 cycles)
4M:
 90.92ns (~290.9 cycles)
 34.96ns (~111.9 cycles)
 91.62ns (~293.2 cycles)
 35.46ns (~113.5 cycles)
8M:
 90.99ns (~291.2 cycles)
 35.04ns (~112.1 cycles)
 91.55ns (~293.0 cycles)
 35.31ns (~113.0 cycles)
16M:
 77.65ns (~248.5 cycles)
 35.38ns (~113.2 cycles)
 78.23ns (~250.4 cycles)
 35.49ns (~113.6 cycles)
32M:
 20.51ns (~65.6 cycles)
 35.47ns (~113.5 cycles)
 20.61ns (~65.9 cycles)
 35.96ns (~115.1 cycles)
64M:
 21.06ns (~67.4 cycles)
 25.61ns (~81.9 cycles)
 20.66ns (~66.1 cycles)
 23.35ns (~74.7 cycles)
128M:
 21.12ns (~67.6 cycles)
 14.64ns (~46.8 cycles)
 20.69ns (~66.2 cycles)
 14.92ns (~47.7 cycles)
```

A significant difference from stride 1MB shows that it's has higher latency when use hugepaged ram(thp and reserved hugepage produce the same result,as i tested).

so is there anything in hardware or os kernel level could cause this confusing result?

Comment: I am not sure of what is measured here (especially with the virtualization), but a latency of 14.64 ns seems pretty small for a DDR4/DDR5 RAM latency, especially since the cache adds some overheads: I am wondering if this is not too small to be correct.

Comment: main purpose of torvalds's code  is to test tbl miss impacts on ram access performance. 
the code using mmap to reserve a fix sized ram(is's fixed 4G above),and set attribute to hugepage or non according param "-H",then read from ram in sequence or random by param "-r". the " 128k 512k 1M ..." means  ram access stride.
while stride is 64M,128M,almost all data is in cpu cache,so 14.64ns is reasonable.but it's not my point here.
by cmdtool perf ,we can see higher L3 cache miss rate on hugepage ram compare to non-hugeped,and ultimately leads to the confusing result i listed above.

Comment: my point is why hugepaged ram could cause such a significant higher access latency (a higher L3 cache miss rate meanwhile) when stride is 1M,2M,4M,16M etc?

Comment: ok,may be it's related to cache coloring,as far as i know.